# Need help with my query

Tags: sql, mysql, database

Sorry for the horrible title, not sure how to explain this. I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT `name`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `indoor`, `address`,
    `phone`, `email`, `website`, `closed`
FROM rocks INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM rock_types WHERE type="DWS" or type="Top rope")
    AS types ON rocks.id=types.id
WHERE (latitude>-180 AND latitude<180) AND (longitude>-180 AND longitude<180)
```

In addition to what I'm getting right now, I'd like to get the list of types associated with each id. How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: Then your title should be something like, "Getting a list of types associated with each ID in SQL"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my take using traditional join syntax:

```
SELECT rocks.name,
       rocks.latitude,
       rocks.longitude,
       rocks.indoor,
       rocks.address,
       rocks.phone,
       rocks.email,
       rocks.website,
       rocks.closed,
       rock_types.type

FROM   rocks,
       rock_types

WHERE  rocks.latitude  > -180                 AND
       rocks.latitude  < 180                  AND
       rocks.longitude > -180                 AND
       rocks.longitude < 180                  AND
       rocks.type_id   = rocks_types.id       AND
       rock_types.type IN ('DWS', 'Top rope')
```

The `rocks.id = rocks_types.id` does the link between both tables.

Here is how you can write the same query using `INNER JOIN` (both leads to the same result)

```
SELECT rocks.name,
       rocks.latitude,
       rocks.longitude,
       rocks.indoor,
       rocks.address,
       rocks.phone,
       rocks.email,
       rocks.website,
       rocks.closed,
       rock_types.type

FROM   rocks
       INNER JOIN rocks_types ON rocks.type_id = rocks_types.id

WHERE  rocks.latitude  > -180                 AND
       rocks.latitude  < 180                  AND
       rocks.longitude > -180                 AND
       rocks.longitude < 180                  AND
       rock_types.type IN ('DWS', 'Top rope')
```

**EDIT**: Based on your comment, the following will give you a comma separated list of types:

```
SELECT rocks.name,
       rocks.latitude,
       rocks.longitude,
       rocks.indoor,
       rocks.address,
       rocks.phone,
       rocks.email,
       rocks.website,
       rocks.closed,
       (SELECT    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT rock_types.type SEPARATOR ',')
        FROM      rock_types
        WHERE     rock_types.id = rocks.id                AND
                  rock_types.type IN ('DWS', 'Top rope')
        GROUP BY  rock_types.id
       ) AS type

FROM   rocks

WHERE  rocks.latitude  > -180    AND
       rocks.latitude  < 180     AND
       rocks.longitude > -180    AND
       rocks.longitude < 180
```

Comment: thank you Andrew. This would work if every rock had only one type associated with. However, that is not always the case. The rocks table is a list of rocks indexed by id. The rock_types table map the id to 1 or more types so for example id=1 might have 2 rows in rock_types, 1 for DWS and 1 for top rope. This query will only return one of those. Is it possible to get all the types associated with that id?

Comment: Ahhh, should of included that in your original question. In which case, let me work this out.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `name`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `indoor`, `address`,
    `phone`, `email`, `website`, `closed`, 
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(type SEPARATOR ',') FROM rock_types 
        WHERE (type="DWS" or type="Top rope") and  rock_types.id=rocks.id group by id) types
FROM rocks 
WHERE (latitude>-180 AND latitude<180) AND (longitude>-180 AND longitude<180)
```